# ereg("^[0-9a-z] restricts only 0-9 and a-z character what about other language character

Tags: php

I have a form and I want to allow users with all character without any space . so I was using this for english character

```
ereg("^[0-9a-z]
```

but later I have decided to allow other character of different languages like arabic, spanish, chinese so I have removed this restriction but after that users started registering with a username with space and for that my website is showing page not found.
so can you please advice what I should use so that I can allow users with different languages to signup for my site

Comment: Don't use the `ereg` functions anyways, as they're depricated ( http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ereg("[^\s]")
```

`^\s` means any character except space.

But please note that `ereg` is deprecated. You should look into `preg_*` functions.

Comment: i tried this function and with this i can register with space in username. in addition if i put this in some other files it gives error.however it is not working as i can register once again with space in username so its not working

Comment: @antyrat  i tried this ereg([^\s]+$",$_POST['username'] but it did not worked . i can register with space again

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ereg`, it's deprected. Instead, use `preg`:

```
preg_match("/^\S+/$", $input_value);
```

Which will match any string with no spaces.

Comment: `[^\s]` can be simplified to `\S`.